# Mapstruct: map list properties by use of a qualified IterableMapping

Tags: java, list, mapping, mapstruct

At first, let me apologize if this question was already posed. I could not find any reference in StackOverflow.

I am trying to use a qualification in my mapping between beans via MapStruct, so as to convert between lists via a qualified mapping. Alas, without success.

Let us suppose we have the following classes (simplified as much as I can, and I will omit obvious getters/setters):

```
public class A {
    private String propertyA;
}
public class B {
    private String propertyB;
    private A instanceA;
}
public class C {
    private List<B> instancesB;
}

public class A1 {
    private String propertyA;
}
public class B1 {
    private String propertyB;
    private A1 instanceA1;
}
public class C1 {
    private List<B1> instancesB1;
}
```

Let us suppose to have the following qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Full{}
```

Let us also suppose to have the following mappings:

```
@Mapper
public interface MapperA {
    A1 toA1(A a);
    A toA(A1 a1);
}
@Mapper
public interface MapperB {
    B1 toB1(B b);
    @Mapping(source="propertyA", target="propertyA1")
    @Full
    B1 toB1Full(B b);
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedBy=Full.class)
    @Full
    List<B1> toB1s(List<B> bs);
    toB(B1 b);
    @Mapping(source="propertyA1", target="propertyA")
    @Full
    toBFull(B1 b);
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedBy=Full.class)
    @Full
    List<B> toBs(List<B1> bs);    
}
@Mapper
public interface MapperC {
    <HERE IS THE PROBLEM>
}
```

How can I write the Mapper C so as to use the full mapping for the iterated instances of B?

No matter how I try to write the annotations for the mapping, such as

```
@Mapping(source = "instancesB1", target="instancesB", qualifiedBy=Full.class)
```

I always find myself with an incomplete mapped entity: the B1 instance has a correctly mapped `propertyB` field, but no `instanceA1`.

I can of course just write `MapperC` as an abstract class, implement the method, call manually the mapper and just be happy with it, but I'm questioning whether it is possible to just annotate somehow the method in `MapperC` and have Mapstruct *automagically* use the correct mapping method for me (since this is an oversimplified case, but I may have tens of such lists to convert).

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have tried that, but looking from the example it seems like the `Mapper#uses` is missing.

In your case it should look something like (omitted the mapping methods):

```
@Mapper
public interface MapperA {

}

@Mapper(uses = MapperA.class)
public interface MapperB {

}

@Mapper(uses = MapperB.class)
public interface MapperC {

}
```

When you use `Mapper#uses` then MapStruct will look for the qualified methods in the classes defined in `uses`. However, if you don't have that then there is nothing MapStruct could do and would generate some default mapping.